# Enzyme test results in null is not an object

Tags: testing, reactjs, karma-runner, enzyme

I'm just getting started with Enzyme and React and i'm a little puzzled.  I've got a simple test passing that doesn't require React.

`src/containers/App/App.spec.js`:

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

describe('hello world', function() {
  it('hello world', () => {
    expect(true).to.be.true;
  })
});
```

`npm test`

```
  hello world
    ✓ hello world

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.011 secs / 0.005 secs)
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS
```

Now I want to do a basic test of my App component, to see if it renders as a div [which it does, when I load it in the browser]. This is where the fails happen.

`src/containers/App/App.spec.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

import App from './App'
import styles from './styles.module.css'

describe('<App />', function () {
  it('renders as a div', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    //wrapper.debug();
    expect(wrapper.type()).to.eql('div');
  })
});
```

`npm test`

```
<App />
    ✗ renders as a div
    null is not an object (evaluating 'ReactInstrumentation.debugTool.onSetDisplayName')
    ShallowComponentWrapper@tests.webpack.js:75869:34
    _render@tests.webpack.js:75919:48
    _batchedRender@tests.webpack.js:75901:20
    batchedUpdates@tests.webpack.js:15977:16
    batchedUpdates@tests.webpack.js:1068:35
    render@tests.webpack.js:75894:31
    render@tests.webpack.js:39176:40
    tests.webpack.js:51532:33
    perform@tests.webpack.js:2952:25
    batchedUpdates@tests.webpack.js:15979:27
    batchedUpdates@tests.webpack.js:1068:35
    tests.webpack.js:51531:42
    withSetStateAllowed@tests.webpack.js:40282:6
    ShallowWrapper@tests.webpack.js:51530:39
    shallow@tests.webpack.js:70431:39
    tests.webpack.js:56497:40


PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.016 secs / 0.005 secs)
```

I want to know what's causing the`null is not an object` error. It makes me feel like we're expecting something to be an `App` object but it isn't?

Here's the actual app rendering the browser:

[image: rendering]

`src/containers/App/App.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import styles from './styles.module.css'

const App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <h1>
          Hello!
        </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = App;
```

`src/app.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'

import './app.css'

import App from 'containers/App/App'

const mountNode = document.querySelector('#root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

Just for references, my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/hjs-dev-server",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.7",
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.9.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-enzyme": "^0.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "cssnano": "^3.7.3",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.4.1",
    "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "hjs-webpack": "^8.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.26",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.9.1",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.2.1",
    "sinon": "^1.17.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "react-router": "^2.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you console.log(wrapper.debug()) ? do you see the div?
also can you just console.log(wrapper.type()) and see what it prints?

Comment: console.log(wrapper.debug()) seems to do nothing? this sounds like a stupid question but where do I see my console output? the terminal message is the same as before

Comment: Hmm there is a console at http://localhost:9876/debug.html, which is putting out this error: debug.js: 21: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onSetDisplayName' of null

Answer (score 2):

---{ Removed original post as wrong } ---

--- edit

**I can now answer this definitively**

the update to react 15.2.1 from react 15.2.0 made some changes.

Result is, react-addons-test-utils will not run in production mode,

The issue is partly related to the fact you are using hjs-webpack.

in production mode, hjs-webpack will perform optimisations and minifications, and react-addons-test-utils (a dependency of enzyme) will not run in this environment as of react 15.2.1

I expect in your webpack you have a prod configuration, a dev configuration and a test configuration. You should make sure that your test configuration includes your dev configuration, otherwise you will be running your tests in production mode.

for example: in your hjs-webpack getConfig object

if you have a webpack.config.js line

```
isDev: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
```

change to:

```
isDev: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems this is a bug introduced in React 15.2.1.  If I downgrade the following packages to strict 15.2.0 in package.json, it fixes the problem.
"react"
"react-dom"
"react-addons-test-utils"

Comment: it's not a bug. React is tidying up something that in their opinion shouldn't have been there.  Therefore, they will not be "fixing" this issue in a later release, and instead the users should understand what needs to change to make it work with up to date react